# Recommended resources for summation identities and manipulations

Tags: summation, algorithms, summation-method

I am taking an algorithms course and am being asked to convert summations to equations. I found [Wikipedia on Summation identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Identities) but I would like to know your preferred resources for this material. I never learned it in school, so I need guides that go over all the basics (maybe even geared toward student/basics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generatingfunctionology
(https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html)

A=B
(https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html)

Concrete Mathematics
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics)

The first two can be downloaded
for free
from the sites indicated.

Comment: Thanks marty. I will mark it answered but I would prefer online articles and course materials if you have any! Hard to hit the Knuth book for every reference question!